# How do I get a variable from a module run space in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, scope, runspace

There is a module that has an "initialize" function that sets a variable that gets used in other scripts/functions in the module to validate that the initialize function was run. Something like

```
Start-InitializeThing
Connect to the API
    
$Script:SNOWinit = $true
```

Then in another script/function it will check:

```
if ($Script:SNOWinit -eq $true) { Do the thing!}
```

Is there a way to grab that $Script:SNOWinit in the same PowerShell window, but not the same module?

I want to run the same check but for a different function that is not in the module.

Can I do this, can I "dig" into like the modules runspace and check that variable. I don't have the means to edit the functions in the module so I cant change what type of variable is set once the initialize script has run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the module of interest is named `foo` *and* that it has already been imported (loaded):

```
. (Get-Module foo) { $SNOWinit }
```

If you want to import the module *on demand*:

```
. (Import-Module -PassThru foo) { $SNOWinit }
```

- The above returns the value of the `$SNOWinit` variable defined in the root scope of module `foo`.

  - See [this blog post](https://seeminglyscience.github.io/powershell/2017/09/30/invocation-operators-states-and-scopes) for background information.
- Note that it is generally *not* advisable to use this technique, because it violates the intended encapsulation that modules provide. In the case at hand, `$SNOWinit`, as a *non-public* module variable, should be considered an *implementation detail*, which is why you shouldn't rely on its presence in production code.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much. That blog post was a good read. I appreciate the note on best practice too. I will reach out to the people that do own the module and see if we can update the way we create the variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the bible, WPiA.  More mysterious uses for the call operator.

```
# get a variable in module scope
$m = get-module counter
& $m Get-Variable count
& $m Set-Variable count 33
```